# Prove that $\Delta(x) = x \otimes1 + 1 \otimes x$ mod $I \otimes I $ for all $x \in I$.

Tags: category-theory, schemes, algebraic-groups, hopf-algebras, group-schemes

I got stuck on this problem, so if anyone can give me a hint on this, I really appreciate.

Let $I$ be the augmentation ideal in Hopf algebra $A$. Prove that $\Delta(x) = x \otimes1 + 1 \otimes x$
mod $I \otimes I $ for all $x \in I$.

Because $I$ is a Hopf ideal, so $\Delta(I) \subset I \otimes A + A \otimes I$. So I can write $\Delta(x) = \sum a_i \otimes b_i + \sum c_i \otimes d_i$, here $a_i, d_i \in I$ and $b_i, c_i \in A$, and the sums are finite. I applied $\epsilon \otimes id$ to have a presentation $x = \sum \epsilon(c_i) \Delta(d_i)$. And I got stuck here. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe the following facts could be of use? 1) $(A,\Delta,\epsilon)$ is a coalgebra, so counitality gives $(\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id})(\Delta(x)) = 1 \otimes x$ and $(\operatorname{id} \otimes \epsilon)(\Delta(x)) = x \otimes 1$. 2) Since $\epsilon: A \to k$ is an algebra homomorphism, we have $\epsilon(1) = 0$. Maybe you can use this to show that $\Delta(x) - x \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes x$ is inside $I \otimes I$.

Comment: @BastiaanCnossen: I think you mean $\epsilon(1) = 1$, right, because algebra homomorphism maps 1 to 1?

Comment: Yeah you're right: $\epsilon(1) = 1$.

Comment: It will follow from 1) and 2) that if $\epsilon(x) = 0$, then $\Delta(x) - x \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes x$ is in the kernel of both $\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id}$ and of $\operatorname{id} \otimes \epsilon$, since for example $(\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id})(\Delta(x) - x \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes x) = 1 \otimes x - 0 \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes x = 0$. I'm not sure whether it helps to conclude that $\Delta(x) - x \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes x$ is in $I \otimes I$ since $\ker(\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id}) \cap \ker(\operatorname{id}\otimes \epsilon)$ might be larger than $I \otimes I$.

Comment: I tried to use your approach, but still unsuccessful. One difficulty is a subtle point that, $(\epsilon \otimes id)(\Delta(x)) = 1 \otimes x \in k \otimes A$, while $\Delta(x) \in A \otimes A$. So if we just replace $1 \otimes x$ by $(\epsilon \otimes id)(\Delta(x))$, it is not well-defined.

Comment: But $(\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id})(1 \otimes x) = \epsilon(1) \otimes x = 1 \otimes x$ also lives in $k \otimes A$ right? We should of course be careful which 1 we mean, but I think this shouldn't result in a problem.

Comment: That's a very nice observation. Using the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow A \rightarrow k \rightarrow 0$, we tensor it with A, then we have $Ker(\epsilon \otimes id) = I \otimes A$ (I hope I don't make any mistake here). So we must have that $\Delta(x) - 1 \otimes x - x \otimes 1 \in (I \otimes A) \cap (A \otimes I)$. Is it equal to $I \otimes I$?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's not true in general, because $A$ is not flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the discussion in the chat is getting too long, let's write down our final conclusions in an answer. We first observe the following:

- Since $(A,\Delta,\epsilon)$ is a coalgebra, the composites
  \begin{aligned}
  A &\xrightarrow{\Delta} A \otimes A \xrightarrow{\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id}} k \otimes A \cong A \\
  A &\xrightarrow{\Delta} A \otimes A \xrightarrow{\operatorname{id}\otimes \epsilon} A \otimes k \cong A
  \end{aligned}
  are the identity of $A$, i.e. we have
  \begin{aligned}
  (\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id})(\Delta(x)) = 1 \otimes x \hspace{20pt} \text{and} \hspace{20pt} (\operatorname{id} \otimes \epsilon)(\Delta(x)) = x \otimes 1.
  \end{aligned}
- Since $\epsilon: A \to k$ is an algebra homomorphism, we have $\epsilon(1) = 1$.

It thus follows that
\begin{aligned}
(\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id})(\Delta(x) - x \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes x) &= 
1 \otimes x - 0 \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes x = 0 \\
(\operatorname{id} \otimes \epsilon)(\Delta(x) - x \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes x) &= 
x \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes 0 - x \otimes 1 = 0
\end{aligned}
and thus $\Delta(x) - x \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes x \in \ker(\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id}) \cap \ker(\operatorname{id}\otimes \epsilon)$. It thus remains to prove that
\begin{aligned}
\ker(\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id}) \cap \ker(\operatorname{id}\otimes \epsilon) = I \otimes I.
\end{aligned}
**Edit** (updated after it turned out $k$ is not assumed to be a field.)
We claim that the short exact sequence
\begin{aligned}
0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{\epsilon} k \rightarrow 0
\end{aligned}
splits. Indeed, the condition $\epsilon(1) = 1$ precisely tells us that the composition
\begin{aligned}
k \to A \xrightarrow{\epsilon} k
\end{aligned}
is the identity. Since split short exact sequences are closed under tensoring, we can tensor the sequence with $A$ to get a short exact sequence
\begin{aligned}
0 \rightarrow I \otimes A \rightarrow A \otimes A \xrightarrow{\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id}} k \otimes A \rightarrow 0,
\end{aligned}
proving that $\ker(\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id}) = I \otimes A$. Similarly we can tensor the above sequence on the left with $I$, giving a short exact sequence
\begin{aligned}
0 \rightarrow I \otimes I \rightarrow I \otimes A \xrightarrow{\operatorname{id} \otimes \epsilon} I \otimes k \rightarrow 0,
\end{aligned}
which shows that
\begin{aligned}
\ker(\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id}) \cap \ker(\operatorname{id}\otimes \epsilon) = I \otimes I.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thanks a lot your your detailed description of our discussion. Unfortunately, we don't have the assumption that $A$ is flat over $k$, so I'm afraid that it is not true. This is actually Exercise 2.3 of Introduction to Affine Group Schemes of Waterhouse. I hope I don't miss anything.

Comment: Also, in the book, $k$ is not assumed to be a field, but just a base ring in general (it is not even an integral domain). You can check page 3, introduction to chapter 1: "That is, we must choose some base ring k of constants".

Comment: But any module over a field $k$ is free (choose a basis using Zorn's lemma) and any free module is flat.

Comment: Okay, I see, that is kinda annoying

Comment: Yeah, I start to doubt if this exercise is correctly stated...

Comment: It is probably correct. We need to use the previous part of the exercise, which writes $A$ as $k \oplus I$. When a short exact sequence splits, we don't need flatness to preserve exactness.

Comment: It's brilliant. I did the previous part, which seems quite trivial for me, and I forgot about it completely. Thanks a lot for your help.